# Cometchat, order by sent date desc

Tags: php, mysql, cometchat

Good day,

I'm looking to order my cometchat chats by last sent date (For example: 1 day ago, 3 days ago, 8 days ago, etc..) for a private messaging system i am working to integrate.

However every time i run the command:

```
(select distinct(f.member_id) id, f.display_name username from    
cometchat m1, members f where (f.member_id = m1.from and m1.to = '1') 
or (f.member_id = m1.to and m1.from = '1')) order by sent desc
```

Which is taken from the official cometchat admin panel, i am correctly displayed the information in question (however it's unorganized. It organizes itself by last member id from the members table. instead of that from cometchat.) This is the example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFvZ6.png

Now, if i use the following command:

```
(select distinct(f.member_id) id,sent, f.display_name username from    
cometchat m1, members f where (f.member_id = m1.from and m1.to = '1') 
or (f.member_id = m1.to and m1.from = '1')) order by sent desc
```

It does output the "sent" times from cometchat, but it also ungroups all the messages sent (so it's like page by page, instead of group messaging.) Proof: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjyzZ.png

So what steps must i take in order to make it so it displays both tables accurately in a grouped format by last sent time?

This is the **Cometchat** table structure: i.imgur.com/s2Nf8xd.png

This is the **members** table structure: i.imgur.com/mcq2Pyp.png

Answer (score 0):

Here is SQL that we would suggest to address this issue:

```
select 
  distinct(f.member_id) id, 
  f.display_name username, 
  max(sent) senttime 
from cometchat m1, members f 
where (f.member_id = m1.from and m1.to = '1') 
   or (f.member_id = m1.to and m1.from = '1') 
group by f.member_id 
order by sent desc
```

The `group_by` keeps messages sent from or to a particular member together.

Comment: I've replied to the email regarding this, but basically: Sort of worked, the only thing that didn't was a last message i sent to a member (The god master) two days ago whereas Zach was sent four days ago. http://imgur.com/a/kW8Zz